# Apex Programming, String and Array Issue

Tags: apex

In Apex, how we can make the following dynamically?

- If SuppliedName = John Doe, then FirstName= John and LastName= Doe
- If SuppliedName = Doe, then LastName = Doe, there should not be FirstName.

Comment: My suggestion is to check whether the SuppliedName value has any whitespace. If yes, use string methods to get substring values and assign it to first name and last name. if you can try and post the code for this, others can correct it in case of any mistakes.

Comment: In Account, LastName is Mandatory. I am not sure whether user/agent through form is going to populate both values, because field is name only. I cant ask 3rd party to make it FirstName and LastName. So I need solution

Comment: If only LastName is mandatory, why do you need to populate the FirstName? You can leave it blank and insert it. What are your requirements for FirstName if any? Can it be populated with anything?

Comment: Also, check out the Apex string documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: You could use `String[] name =SuppliedName.split(' '); if name.len() <2 //only last name exists else // both last and first name `

Comment: Without using explicit delimiting in the name it would be impossible to guarantee appropriate formatting, due to the ability for a person to have multiple name combinations for first/last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go this route:

```
    String[] name = String.isBlank(SuppliedName) ? New String[]{} : SuppliedName.split('\\s+');

    if(name.size() > 1){
        FirstName = name.remove(0);
    }

    LastName = string.join(name,' ');
```

You will have to add in some code to identify Dr, Mr, Ms, Miss, Etc for the Salutations but as long as names are like "Fred Wilson" or "Joan De Williams" it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

> **Scenario:**

1. SuppliedName = 'John Doe'; then FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Doe';
2. SuppliedName = 'Doe'; then FirstName = null and LastName = 'Doe'
3. SuppliedName = 'Dr John Doe'; then FirstName = 'Dr John' and LastName = 'Doe';

Your logic will look like this:

```
String SuppliedName = 'John Doe';
String LastName = null;
String FirstName = null;

Integer position = SuppliedName.lastIndexOf(' ');
if(position != -1)
{
    LastName = SuppliedName.substring(position + 1, SuppliedName.length());
    FirstName = SuppliedName.substring(0,position);
}
else
{
    LastName = SuppliedName;
}

System.debug('FirstName=' + FirstName);
System.debug('LastName=' + LastName);
```

Refer: [String Class and Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

Comment: This runs into the same issue as I commented in Mahood's answer, that it is fairly difficult to tell exactly what the format _should_ be without explicit delimiting. It is uncommon, but not impossible, for people to have a last name that is a compound of two or more names. This is a good approach, but it will be difficult to guarantee consistency unless, again, a more specific delimiting methodology is used. If they passed "Dr John, Doe" using the comma as a delimiter, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
String[] name =SuppliedName.split(' '); 
for(integer index = 0; index < name.size(); index++) 
{
    if(name[index] == '') name.remove(index); 
}
if (name.size() <2 ) //only last name exists 
else // both last and first name
```

Comment: The downside  to this approach, at least in its current form, is that a user may have more than one first or last name. For example, if someone entered the name in the format "Jean Claude van Damme". Logic could probably be made to account for this, but it is hard to guarantee formatting is broken by spaces.

Comment: It can be done easily, provided if the name format is decided, you pick the last element in the `string[]` and set it to last name or vice versa, depending on the name format you are going to follow. Otherwise without user intervention or guidance, there is no way to determine the firstname and lastname automatically.

Comment: That is my point :) This is a good answer, but it is not guaranteed to properly format the name.